# Can I do multiple binomial tests seperately of each other?

Tags: r, regression, lme4-nlme, binomial-distribution, glmm

in the experiment the subjects had to choose between answer A and answer B in 3 different settings. The question is, if there is a significant preference for answer A in any of the settings.

Can I just do a binomial test for all of the 3 settings? Or is there a way to link these 3 tests? Is there a multiple comparisons issue?

Comment: What is the hypothesis you wish to test?

Comment: @utobi Is there a preference for answer A in any of the settings?

Comment: sorry, it was actually written...I read it too quickly!

Comment: You'd have a 3x2 contingency table to test with a Chi-square test.

Answer (score 2):

A possible answer to your research question can be obtained by a mixed binary logistic regression. The model can be explained as follows.

Let $Y_{is}$ be your `answer` variable such that $Y_{is}=0$ if the answer is A and $Y_{is}=1$ if the answer is B for every individual $i=1,\ldots,n$ at any setting $s=1,2,3$. Assuming $Y_{is}$ is independent from $Y_{js}$ for all $i\neq j\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$, then we assume

\begin{align*}
Y_{is} & \sim \text{Bernoulli}(p_{is})\\
p_{is} &= \frac{\exp(\alpha_{i}+\beta_0)}{1+\exp(\alpha_{i}+\beta_0)}\\
\alpha_i&\sim N(0,\sigma_{\alpha}^2),
\end{align*}

where $\alpha_i$ are unknown random intercepts assumed to be independent.

The parameters, to be estimated from data, are $\beta_0,\sigma^2_\alpha$. In particular, $\beta_0$ is your parameter of interest: if $\beta_0\neq0$ means that the proportion of the zeros and ones (e.g. A's and B's) in your response are different. The random effects $\alpha_i$ are useful for handling the dependence in the response due to repeated sampling.

You can fit this model in `R` using the `glmer` function from the `lme4` package, e.g. something like

```
mm <- glmer(y~1+(1|patientID), data=mydata, family=binomial)
summary(mm)
```

In the summary, look for the estimate of the intercept and the associate p-value or build a confidence interval. The summary will also provide an estimate for $\sigma_\alpha^2$.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! One thing I forgot to mention, two of the 3 settings were repeated. So each participant answered 5 questions, two settings were done 2 times and one setting a single time. Is this problematic here? There is also some missing data but the model can handle that, right?

Comment: Can you explain what is the difference between the settings then? I thought the settings were the repetition themselves, but it seems that they are kind of experimental conditions...

Comment: Yes they are experimental conditions. The experimenters try to influence the decision making in two specific ways. Those are done for 2 questions each.. For one question, they don't influence the participant at all and let them choose freely between answer A and B. The order of these conditions are randomised for each participant.

Comment: If you are not interested in the differences between the three experimental conditions, but only in the difference between the proportions A vs B, the model above is ok. If you are also interested in the differences between the experimental conditions, then you have to add the factor 'experimental conditions' (two dummies) in the model and test for two associated coefficients being equal to zero; the formula, in this case, would be `y~1+conditions + (1|patientID)`.

Comment: I am struggling to write out the model including the experimental conditions, where would you add these dummies? Also, why in the original model does the p have an s index when the s is not used in the formular?

Comment: @FionaGharamber `R` with include the dummy variables for you. Do you mean the $s$ in $p_{is}$? If so, $s$ identifies the replications, you are taking care of s, by including the term `(1|patientID)`. If you show a portion of your data I could update the post with `R` code tailored to your data.

Comment: No I mean in the formular: \begin{align*}
p_{is} &= \frac{\exp(\alpha_{i}+\beta_0)}{1+\exp(\alpha_{i}+\beta_0)}\\
\end{align*} \\ should it be $ \alpha_{is} $ here? Otherwise the s is not used in the formular. How does the full model look like if we are also interested int the differences between the conditions?

Comment: No, it goes without $s$. To include also $s$ you need to have a further nesting level, e.g. replications at each time point., which you do not have. As I wrote above, if you wish to test also for differences between conditions use `y~1+conditions+(1|patientID)`, supposing `conditions` is the factor variable of interest.

Comment: For some reason the estimate and p-value of the intercept changes drastically depending on if I include the dummy variables myself or let R do it automatically. So: ```y ~ 1 + conditions + (1|patientID)``` yields a different result as ```y ~ 1 + condition1 + condition2 + (1|patientID)```.  Can you explain that difference?

Comment: It's hard to tell without knowing how you build `condition1` and `condition2`. Are you using the same baseline category as in `1 + conditions`?

Comment: The baseline category in conditions is the control setting when the experimentors did not try to influence the decision making. Condition1 and Condition2 are dummy variables that are 1 in the settings when the experimenters tries to influence the participant in a certain way and 0 otherwise. So the df looks like "control" "0" "0"   in the control setting

Comment: As I said, without data+code it's hard to tell. Anyway, this question is not related to your original post. I suggest posting another separate question on this.